# how to use roscd with folders which are not ros nodes?

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently using ROS in conjunction with Genom. However, Genom doesn't have an equivalent to roscd. I would like to know if there is a way to use roscd to fastly go into Genom module folders.

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10044/how-to-use-roscd-with-folders-which-are-not-ros-nodes-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just add a magical fake manifest.xml file to your folder. And be sure to put the name of your folder in the manifest at the right places (refere to an example manifest to see where the package name must appear).

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-05-25**:
Yes indeed. You are disguising your folders into ros packages.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-24**:
So essentially, you are turning your folder into a ROS package. (What is a ROS package other than a folder with a manifest.xml in it?)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need any arcane magic such as artificial manifests. They set up an environment variable for that which you can set in your setup.sh. See the ros wiki for environment variables, and in particular [ROS_LOCATIONS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_LOCATIONS) for more details. e.g. in setup.sh:

```
export ROS_LOCATIONS="motors=/opt/diamondback/ycs/ycs_devices/motors"
```

After making sure the variable is set in my shell:

```
> snorri@snorriheim:/opt/diamondback$ roscd motors
> snorri@snorriheim:/opt/diamondback/ycs/ycs_devices/motors$ ls
actuator  goo  goo_firmware  qgoo
```

Those listed by ls are actual ros packages, but it works equally as well on any directory outside your ros tree.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-05-24**:
I tryied with and without S. But i didn't used name=... If you put it like this, it works. However, I prefere having files in my folders rather than a long ROS_LOCATIONS :). Anyway your solution is a good one. Thanks.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-05-24**:
Seems to work for me without manifests. Are you sure you used ROS_LOCATIONS and not ROS_LOCATION? See edit above.

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-05-24**:
Simply using ROS_LOCATION is not enough. I think roscd verify if the given name is indeed a package. So you do need arcane magic for this (if creating a file is what you call magic).